# Binary Tree storing any data type in c

Tags: c, pointers, tree, binary-tree, void

i'm currently implementing a binary tree in c. After getting the code to work for inserting ints I now want the tree to be able to store any date type i.e. char etc. I'm kind of stumped about how to go about this. I've heard/seen that I can use a void* within my node struct but unsure how you then implement this with regards to inserting elements and comparing void* to see which is bigger or smaller. Any help would be very much appreciated! Thanks

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

//struct for node of the binary tree
struct node
{
    void *value;
    struct node *p_left;
    struct node *p_right;
};

//recursive function to allow users to input into the tree
void insert(void* key, struct node** leaf )
{

if( *leaf == NULL )
{
    *leaf = (struct node*) malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
    (*leaf)->value = key;
    (*leaf)->p_left = NULL;
    (*leaf)->p_right = NULL;
    printf(  "\nnew node " );
}
else if( key < (*leaf)->value )
   {
    printf(  "\ngoing left " );
    insert( key, &(*leaf)->p_left );

   }
else if(key > (*leaf)->value)
   {
    printf(  "\ngoing right " );
    insert( key, &(*leaf)->p_right );
   }
}

int main(void)
{
struct node *p_root = NULL;
int value ; //i want value to be of any kind

printf(  "\nPlease enter a value: " );
scanf( "%d", &value );
insert(value,  &p_root);

return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Well comparing would be the hard part, you would have to come up with a way to compare elements of different types i.e. How do you compare a string and float? I think that is something to try and figure out before you start coding that part.

Comment: Be passed to the `insert` function by creating a function for comparison(`int cmpInt(const void*, const void*)`,`int cmpStr(const void*, const void*)`).

Comment: thank you @BLUEPIXY so much can you please explain how this line works though: `return *a < *b ? -1 : *a > *b;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    void *value;
    struct node *p_left;
    struct node *p_right;
};

typedef int (*Compare)(const void *, const void *);

void insert(void* key, struct node** leaf, Compare cmp){
    if( *leaf == NULL ){
        *leaf = (struct node*) malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
        (*leaf)->value = key;
        (*leaf)->p_left = NULL;
        (*leaf)->p_right = NULL;
        printf(  "\nnew node " );
    } else if( cmp(key,  (*leaf)->value) < 0) {
        printf(  "\ngoing left " );
        insert( key, &(*leaf)->p_left, cmp);
    } else if( cmp(key, (*leaf)->value) > 0){
        printf(  "\ngoing right " );
        insert( key, &(*leaf)->p_right, cmp);
    } else {
        free(key);
    }
}

int CmpInt(const int *a, const int *b){
    return *a < *b ? -1 : *a > *b;
}

int *GetInteger(void){
    char line[16];
    printf("Please enter a value : ");
    if(fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)){
        int v, *ret;
        char *p;
        v = strtol(line, &p, 10);
        if(*p == '\n' || *p == '\0'){
            int *ret = malloc(sizeof(*ret));
            *ret = v;
            return ret;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

void print_tree(struct node *root, void (*print_func)(const void*) ){
    if(root){
        print_tree(root->p_left, print_func);
        print_func(root->value);
        print_tree(root->p_right, print_func);
    }
}

void print_int(const void *p){
    printf("%d ", *(int*)p);
}

int main(void){
    struct node *p_root = NULL;
    void *value;//int *value;

    while(value = GetInteger()){//upto input EOF or invalid input
        insert(value,  &p_root, (Compare)CmpInt);
    }

    print_tree(p_root, print_int);
    //release tree omit 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you @BLUEPIXY so much can you please explain how this line works though: `return *a < *b ? -1 : *a > *b;`

Comment: @JamieConnelly `if(*a < *b) return -1; if(*a > *b) return 1;if(*a==*b) return 0;`

Comment: `*a > *b`  becomes 0 when it is not satisfied to 1 when the conditional expression in C is satisfied

Answer (score 1):

You should use void pointers for inserting values and then cast them to their supposed types after.

The thing is, you do not wan't to get "anything" if you know you want to compare which is bigger or smaller later. I suppose you might want to have an additional info in your node which specifies what type is the value actually.

I suppose you want to do this for practice, but in reality would you really want to compare arrays of characters with integers?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah it is just for practise, should I cast them within the insert function? Sorry i'm quite new to pointers